# Choosing Language on Mobile Game

Tags: game-design, mobile, localization

Currently I'm trying to localize a mobile game into popular language.

Apart from technical stuff (like how to store string and including supporting fonts),
I'm a bit confused about designing two things: choosing first language when they play game for the first time and changing between them

Currently, I already have several options about choosing first language:

1. Language is chosen programatically based on user's default
   language/font
2. Ask user on first time run to choose which language thay want
3. Just set default language to english

About changing language, is it necessary to give user the option to change language? (assuming that my localization team is really good without any flaw when localizing this mobile game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from technical issues, that's something you get to choose for yourself. There are lots of games/programs that use each of those approaches, so you have to ask yourself what gives a better UX for your users.

In my opinion:

1. Choose system language: This is my preferred choice. I dare say the vast majority of users use and expect this. Those who want a language different from the OS language are a minority, and are accustomed to changing their language in the settings menu.
2. Ask on first run: This was popular in the past when most people used the same english version of the OS (DOS anybody?). Also it's probably the easiest to implement. I don't think it's the best UX though.
3. Set default to english: Don't do this because a lot of people who could benefit from other languages would probably not even know the language is changeable. Remember that most users won't even see your settings menu. An exception could be highly technical apps, or apps that have incomplete/experimental translations, and english is a sensible default.

Also, try asking this at the [UXSE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for language in a new screen. And later the users can change the language when they want, i.e. in pause screen or in main menu. You are free to choice!

Answer (score 0):

**There is no standard way of doing this. This is purely a marketing feature.**

The most logical way to do this would be to use the default language of the OS of the mobile device as all mobile devices have that feature. Don't ask the user.

Then in the options offer to change the language *if you want*. You could consider it a hassle, a wast of time and money as often the option will not be used.